# How to generate UUID in spring boot 2

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, uuid

Hello StackOverflow Community

I am using spring boot 2.7 and mysql 8. I am using hibernate to generate a column with UUID values (different from my primary key) but getting this error

```
not-null property references a null or transient value
```

Code

```
@GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    @Column(name = "campaignId", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.UUIDCharType")
    private UUID campaignId;
```

Tried various things but nothing seem to be working. I just need the system to generate a unique id.

Answer (score 0):

It should simply "work" with this:

```
@Entity
class Campaign {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID campaignId;

    . . .
}
```

If you must be more explicit then define the column specification too:

```
@Entity
class Campaign {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = "campaignId", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(36)", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @Type(type = "uuid-char")
    private UUID campaignId;

    . . .
}
```

Comment: shows a null value in the DB

Comment: And you have a getter and a setter for campaignId ? It is really hard to figure out what else could be going on based on the limited information provided.

Comment: public UUID getCampaignId() {
  return campaignId;
 }

 public void setCampaignId(UUID campaignId) {
  this.campaignId = campaignId;
 }